Angular 14 and Electron js Outlook integration doesn't work after creadentials given
We have used
@azure/msal-angular

For outlook integration in our system.
let result = await this.msalService
        .loginPopup({
          scopes: [
            'user.read',
            'Mail.ReadWrite',
            'Mail.ReadBasic',
            'Mail.Read',
            'Mail.Send',
          ],
        })
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
          console.log('Login success', res);
          this.localService.setJsonValue(
            'outlookEmailAccessToken',
            res.accessToken
          );
          this.fetchOutlookEmails();
        });

The above code shows how we are able to show the popup in the angular and its working fine with web but then we are using electron with angular then its showing the popup but not able to redirect properly. Its when trying to redirect its making the electron application fail.
Versions:
angular: 14
electron:
^21.3.0

I want to handle the redirects properly and outlook authentication with angular and electron js should work perfectly
